# Ubuntu 20.04 VMWare EXSI VLAN Remote Connection Lost after Kubeadm install

Tags: ssh, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, kubernetes

While setting up a Kubernetes environment for studying for CKA exam using the Linux Foundation environment instructions, I started being unable to SSH into my Ubuntu 20.04 controller and worker after about 2 minutes after boot. The environment utilizes VMWare EXSI to create and manage the VMs. I have a PfSense instance running with the Kubernetes VMs running within a VLAN behind the PfSense firewall. There doesn't appear to be an blocking from PfSense as I am able to take my time to install Kubernetes. The problem only came about after installing Kubernetes with Cilium. Kubernetes version is 1.27 and Cilium version is 1.14.4. I am able to interact with the machine successfully through the VMWare console. Not sure if anyone else has experienced this and has some suggestions on being able to remote into the VMs without using the VMWare console for the VM.

I have permanently disabled the swap. There is no traffic that appears to be blocked by the PfSense firewall. SSH service is running. SSH port is listening and doesn't appear to be blocked. Pinging the VM from my local machine from the PfSense WAN times out after the 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is reproduceable? Things works fine, you install kubeadm or other k8s related software, then the SSH connection no longer works?

output of 'ss -ptuln' will show you if the ssh port is open and listening, and on what interfaces. 'iptables -nL' and/or 'systemctl status ufw' will show you have firewall status. If you're positive you can replicate this issue, you will need to snapshot the VM before installing the k8s software and seeing if anything changed (eg, ssh listening, local firewall rules via iptables, ufw) and revert back if needed to change anything to prevent this.